find if partition key exists in dynamodb
I need to check if a partition key exists (email) in a dynamodb table
I am using an astro action with typescript and the error it returns is:

ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

I can see it in the console and if I search for it it will find it.
What am I doing wrong?
table
policies:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/xxxx"
      },
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:GetItem",
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:Scan"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xxx:xxxxx:table/votos"
    }
  ]
}

error:
ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
at throwDefaultError (C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@smithy+smithy-client@3.4.2\node_modules@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\index.js:836:20)
at C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@smithy+smithy-client@3.4.2\node_modules@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\index.js:845:5
at de_CommandError (C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@aws-sdk+client-dynamodb@3.677.0\node_modules@aws-sdk\client-dynamodb\dist-cjs\index.js:2233:14)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@smithy+middleware-serde@3.0.8\node_modules@smithy\middleware-serde\dist-cjs\index.js:35:20
at async C:\visual_studio\votacionl\node_modules.pnpm@aws-sdk+lib-dynamodb@3.677.0_@aws-sdk+client-dynamodb@3.677.0\node_modules@aws-sdk\lib-dynamodb\dist-cjs\index.js:166:30
at async C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@smithy+core@2.5.1\node_modules@smithy\core\dist-cjs\index.js:168:18
at async C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@smithy+middleware-retry@3.0.25\node_modules@smithy\middleware-retry\dist-cjs\index.js:320:38
at async C:\visual_studio\votacion\node_modules.pnpm@aws-sdk+middleware-logger@3.667.0\node_modules@aws-sdk\middleware-logger\dist-cjs\index.js:34:22
at async chequeaVoto (C:/visual_studio/votacion/src/actions/index.ts:53:20) {
'$fault': 'client',
'$metadata': {
httpStatusCode: 400,
requestId: 'sfadfasfasfas',
extendedRequestId: undefined,
cfId: undefined,
attempts: 1,
totalRetryDelay: 0
},
__type: 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'
}

code:
import { dynamodb } from "@/aws";
import { GetCommand, PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

async function chequeaVoto(emailVoto: string): Promise<string | false> {
  console.log("emailVoto llego:", emailVoto);
  const params = {
    TableName: "votos",
    Key: {
      email: emailVoto,
    },
  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.send(new GetCommand(params));
    console.log("Resultado de la consulta chequeo:", result.Item);
    // Verifica si existe el item y devuelve el voto o false
    return result.Item ? result.Item.voto : false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en la consulta:", error);
    return false; // Devuelve false en caso de error
  }
}


One question is why you're checking to see if the email exists? I ask because you may be better off adding a condition to a PutItem/UpdateItem, like attribute_not_exists(email), if your goal is to only add a user with that email if it doesn't already exist.

I use the email to check if I have already voted, if there is already a vote and you cannot vote again

In that case, the condition would be perfect - call PutItem, add the condition, and the put will fail if you've already voted.

You're using a GetItem command which expects a full primary key as parameter, however you only pass the partition key. To use just the partition key, simply change the command to QueryCommand:
import { dynamodb } from "@/aws";
import { QueryCommand, PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

async function chequeaVoto(emailVoto: string): Promise<string | false> {
  console.log("emailVoto llego:", emailVoto);
  const params = {
    TableName: "votos",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#a = :v",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#a": "email"
    }, 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v": emailVoto
    }

  };

  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.send(new QueryCommand(params));
    console.log("Resultado de la consulta chequeo:", result.Items);
    // Verifica si existe el item y devuelve el voto o false
    return result.Items ? result.Items[0].voto : false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en la consulta:", error);
    return false; // Devuelve false en caso de error
  }
}


Thanks Hannigan! and... in terms of cost, if I add a sorting key (always be 1 since it will be a single time per email) would it be cheaper to use getItem?

if there is only 1 item the Query will have the exact same performance and cost profile as GetItem.
